# How create a circle in the center of the pie chart in react-native-chart-kit?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I am using react-native-chart-kit. I have a pie chart. I need create a cicle white in middle of chart, but I do not find in the documentation any property or way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the module but I might give a solution to you. Why dont you create a relative parent div with thow absolute child div. this way you can add the chart and on top of it place a white circle